# Support of a convolution: where is compactness used

Tags: real-analysis, support-function

$\def\supp{\operatorname{supp}}$
I've found some questions about this, but couldn't find an answer that had what I needed. I'm asked to prove that if $f,g \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and $\supp(f)$ is compact then $\supp(f*g) \subseteq \supp(f) + \supp(g)$. I must have an error somewhere, but I wrote the following:

Let $x \in \supp(f*g)$, then, exists $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ with $(f*g)(x_n) \neq 0 \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $x_n \rightarrow x$. Since $(f*g)(x_n)=\int f(t)g(x_n-t) dt$ it must exist some $H \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ with $|H|>0$ such that $f(h)g(x_n-h) \neq 0$, for any $h \in H$, so choosing any of these $h$ as $h_n$, I have that $h_n \in \supp(f)$, $x_n -h_n \in \supp(g)$ and $x_n \in \supp(f) + \supp(g)$, so when $n \rightarrow \infty$, $x \in \supp(f) + \supp(g)$

My problem here is that I don't see where I used that $\supp(f)$ is compact nor $f,g \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$

Comment: $f,g \in L^1$ is mostly a technical assumption to ensure that $f*g$ is defined in $L^1$. Note however that it implies that $f,g$ are not necessarily well-defined at points and that the definition of support of $f$ may not be as easy as considering the support of a function ae equal to $f$. As for the compactness of the support of $f$, it's because otherwise the RHS isn't closed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand the part of $L^1$ now, but don't understand why would I need the RHS to be closed, just to contain the LHS. In this case, haven't I proved that if there is a point in $supp(f*g)$ then it is in $supp(f) + supp(g)$?

Comment: @Silkking. How is $\supp{f}$ defined for $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

Comment: BTW. You are using $n$ for two different things: dimension of space and sequence index.

Comment: Are $H$ and $h$ supposed to be the same symbol?

Comment: Do you really have to take a sequence $(x_n)$?

Comment: I think that your proof is basically correct. But you need to make it clean. You have missed saying some things, and have errors in the notation.

Comment: @md2perpe
I just modified the question so $n$ isn't at the same time a dimension and an index of the sequence. 

Maybe there is a way without taking the sequence, but It's what I thought. Any suggestion for another approach? Thanks

$supp(f)=\bar{\{x\in \mathbb{R}^d : f(x) \neq 0\}}$ and $h \in H$

Comment: $supp(f)=\bar{\{x\in \mathbb{R}^d : f(x) \neq 0\}}$

$h \in H$

Comment: For continuous functions, yes, but not so in $L^1$. As an example, consider the set $A$ of the $1/n, n \geq 1$, and let $f=1_A$. The $L^1$-support of $f$ is empty.

Comment: @Silkking. If $h \in H,$ why don't you say that in your proof?

Comment: @Silkking. At the end you seem to use $x_n \to x.$ But when you introduce $(x_n)$ you do not say that $x_n \to x.$ You have only taken *some* sequence on $x_n$ for which $(f*g)(x_n) \neq 0.$

Comment: Sorry, I wrote both in my notes and forgot to write it here. I'll edit it right away

Comment: Your argument gives $$x \in \overline{\operatorname{supp}(f) + \operatorname{supp}(g)}\,.$$ The sum of two closed sets is not necessarily closed, so to get rid of the closure in this, you need some condition that guarantees $\operatorname{supp}(f) + \operatorname{supp}(g)$ is closed. One of the two supports being compact guarantees that.